# Renaming Maven dependency in WAR's WEB-INF/lib folder

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-3

I need to have a JAR dependency in the Maven generated WAR's `WEB-INF/lib` folder as `x-1.0.final.jar` instead of `x-1.0.jar`, which is the name it has in the repository. What would be the best way to achieve this?

In my POM I have:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>x</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I want this to appear in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder as `x-1.0.final.jar`.

It's and external dependency on Maven Central I don't have control over. Also I don't want to force everyone using this to redeploy the dependency to their local repositories.

Is there a Maven plugin that I could utilize or should I start coding my own?

Comment: How are you going to get them to find the library if you cannot put it online and don't want them to put it locally?

Comment: It is an external third-party dependency. And it is online at Maven Central. The name of the JAR is the one that doesn't apply my usage. I want to rename what goes into the `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Comment: I don't think such a solution exist for renaming what goes in to the folder.

Comment: You could try to write your own maven plugin to do that.

Comment: Well, I think so too unless there'd be one doing this already.

Comment: To summarise, you want maven to get `x-1.0.jar` from central repo and rename it before it goes into `WEB-INF/lib`. Are you planning to add your own `x-1.0.jar`? That can cause serious problem when your servlet container try to load the classes, if two jars has the same class names and packages. I am not sure that I understand you correctly. If you are planning to add you own ``x-1.0.jar`, why don't you just make it available online in a private repository under different classifier.

Comment: Well, it's all about the Google plugin for Eclipse that I use to run my Google App Engine applications inside the IDE. It expects that in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder there's a JAR named `datanucleus-appengine-1.0.8.final.jar` otherwise it'll add it. Lately the Google App Engine dependencies have been made available in Maven Central, but the `datanucleus-appengine` has version `1.0.8`. So, I'll end up the same library twice which causes classpath errors as you mentioned. To tackle this I thought I could rename the dependency that goes to `WEB-INF/lib`. Hope this clears out my intentions.

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/skinny-wars.html  I have not used it myself but it seems to beable to exclude jar from war.

Comment: That should do the trick, but it seems inconsistent. Sometimes the file is there but running `mvn eclipse:eclipse` again removes it.

Comment: Note that unless you have a very good reason for needing it to be something very specific, you do not have to change the name in the lib folder.  I found it not to be worth the trouble.

Comment: It makes sense to want to change a library's name. We're now in the realm of open source, we include many artifacts developed by uncoordinated teams. What if you get to include both com.foo:utils:1.0 and org.bar.filesystem:utils:2.3? You'll get two utils-x.y.jar which looks confusing.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use `maven-dependency-plugin` to include artifact under the name that you need.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId>foo</groupId>
              <artifactId>x</artifactId>
              <version>1.0</version>
              <type>jar</type>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
              <destFileName>x-1.0.final.jar</destFileName>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

By default, `maven-dependency-plugin` is bound to the `process-sources` phase that seems just enough for your task. Remember to set the scope `provided` for the artifact in dependencies so that it is not automatically included by the `war` plugin.

Comment: This solution exclude all dependencies of renamed library

Comment: be careful destFileName must be in artifactItem elements, mine was outside and it did not work. when I copied into under artifactItem tag problem disappeared

Comment: This is a good start.  If you leav the dependency to be renamed as a regular dependency, you will get all the transitive dependencies included.  Then edit <packingExcludes> in the war plugin to exclude the x.jar.  Gives you the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to see if the [outputFileNameMapping](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/file-name-mapping.html) parameter of [maven war plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) can help you.

Answer (score 3):

I know that I'm replying to an old thread, but I needed to perform the above and found this thread helpful. The way I found to achieve this was to perform a 2 step process:

1. Use the maven-war-plugin to exclude the original jar file from the deliverable.
2. Use the maven-dependency-plugin to copy the original jar file to the new-named jar file and place this in the WEB-INF/lib directory.

So, by way of illustration, this is how to specify the file you wish to exclude. In this case x-1.0.jar :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- Exclude file: x-1.0.jar from packaging -->
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/x-1.0.jar</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Also specify that a copy must be performed of the file to the new name (x-1.0.final.jar) but this needs to run BEFORE packaging occurs. This is specified by the phase: 'prepare-package':

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>the group of the x jar</groupId>
                        <artifactId>x</artifactId>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <destFileName>x-1.0.final.jar</destFileName>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In my example I wasn't hard-coding 1.0 but I think this should work for the original posters question.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I dont understand your question fully what is the code you have for importing this jar in the POM?

If the Jar you wish to import is called that in the repository and you are importing the correct file in your POM then you shouldn't have to worry about naming conventions of the JAR file.

What i believe you may have to do is rename the file in the repository you can do this simply by going into the Repository Users/.m2 in a explorer window and tracking down the file and renaming it, note this may have implications on other projects.

What i suggest you do is copy the file rename it and add it to the repository with the new artifact id x-1.0.final.jar

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
-DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

fill in the <>

Hope this helps 
Chris

Comment: The repository has one name for the JAR, which is different from what I need to have on my WAR. I don't have control over the remote repository and don't want to force everyone using this to redeploy the dependency into their local repositories.