# Maven Unique Version in Jar File Name

Tags: maven-2, hudson, nexus

I am using Maven with Nexus for building my project with hudson ci. Everytime when I am deploying a new snapshot artifact he is doing this with a unique version in nexus. Which is OK for me as Nexus is giving me always the latest version.

Now I looked into the war file of my project which is using this snapshot dependency and its having the following jar file in its lib directory which is absolutely not fine:

framework-client-1.1-20120302.141044-3.jar

The problem is that I am using EBean as an ORM and I need to specify the jar name in the ebean.properties to let him know where to find its models.

How can I prevent such behaviour so that the latest snapshot dep is always call framework-client-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar?

Thank you!

Comment: Which Maven version? How does your settings.xml look like?

Comment: Maven 3.0.3 and JDK 6(24). My settings.xml is almost standard except the mirror settings for nexus

Comment: Have you configured to use uniqueVersion in the mirror settings for the nexus repository ?

Comment: No and it has no effect as well: https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html

Comment: Have you configured the uniqueVersion in your distributionManagement block ? (http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repository)

Comment: Have you tried using the finalName property?

Comment: Maven probably does have a config setting to change this behaviour but if not, maybe also try looking into the EBean settings/config, does it have any options for specifying a JAR name or can it use wildcards or anything like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rename the jar in the war file to whatever name you like. Details are here

[Renaming Maven dependency in WAR's WEB-INF/lib folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969313/renaming-maven-dependency-in-wars-web-inf-lib-folder)

Comment: I would only agree with this option if there is no config to fix the root problem. This seems like just a hack/work-around which doesn't fix the real issue.

Comment: Well... this is the fix if you need it to work in development. If you use a non-snapshot version you will not need it. So if you like you can just have this in a dev profile and just leave it out for the release profile..  you will have to accept that snapshots get deployed as time stamp named artifacts.. thats how it is.

Comment: I am fairly certain that you can configure maven to not uniquely identify snapshots because I remember needing to do it a couple years ago in maven 2. If not though, you are right, renaming the JAR put into the WAR is an appropriate solution.

Comment: On deployment to a repo server it will always get the timestamp if it is a snapshot... no choice about that, if you try to circumvent that you will break the notion of a SNAPSHOT which will cause you a lot more pain.. dont fight maven, it always ends in tears or wasted effort ;-)