# Maven war and put the version number in the jars in WEB-INF/lib

Tags: java, maven

If I have a war configuration which builds a standard war file with a WEB-INF/lib directory.  The jar files come out as spring-core.jar.  Is it possible to include the version number that are listed in the dependency list, e.g.  I want to have a war with version numbers,

WEB-INF/lib/spring-4.3.8.RElEASE.jar

Instead  of:

WEB-INF/lib/spring.jar

```
 <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <outputFileNameMapping>@{artifactId}@.@{extension}@</outputFileNameMapping>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>WebContent</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: If you remove the `outputFileNameMapping` than it should work.

Comment: Is that the output name of the war or ALL artifacts in the web-inf/lib

Comment: This is the correct answer, can you add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default name is whatever it's called in the repository. You may have a configuration overriding this feature (such as stripVersion from the maven-dependency-plugin).

This question describes the process of renaming a single dependency:
[Renaming Maven dependency in WAR's WEB-INF/lib folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969313/renaming-maven-dependency-in-wars-web-inf-lib-folder).

Comment: The repository is maven2 or the default maven.   If I build those projects separately as a jar, they have the version number.  But in the war, it does not have the version in the name of the file.  It looks like the maven-dependency manager is OK but do you have an example where I can parameterize the names of my jar files globally.